# How can I verify a certificate chain when X509 extensions are incorrect?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, x509certificate, public-key-encryption

I have a PKI certificate chain that has issues with the X.509 extensions related to CA values.

Root: fine

Intermediate: specifies pathlen:1

```
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:1
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
```

CA: specifies pathlen:0

```
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
```

Sub-CA1: missing CA Basic Constraints entirely

Sub-certificate2: also missing CA Basic, but it's the bottom of the chain in this case.

When I run openssl verify I get expected errors given the state of the chain:

```
  openssl verify -CAfile "Root.crt" -untrusted "ICA.crt" -untrusted "CA.crt" -untrusted sub-CA1.pem Sub-certificate2.pem
CN = sub-CA1
error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate
CN = CA
error 25 at 2 depth lookup: path length constraint exceeded
CN = ICA, O = organization
error 25 at 3 depth lookup: path length constraint exceeded
error Sub-certificate2: verification failed
```

How can I verify that the certificates were in fact signed by the certificates, independent of the broken X509 constraints?

I'm open to openssl parameters (I couldn't find anything in my searching) or example python/other code.

Comment: You can do one link in the chain at a time: `openssl verify -CAfile root ICA; openssl verify -CAfile ICA -partial_chain CA; openssl verify -CAfile CA -partial_chain subCA; ...`. But this is not programming or development. If you really want to verify just the signature manually, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127095/manually-walking-through-the-signature-validation-of-a-certificate (disclosure: I contributed to the answer)

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085. Unfortunately your suggestion still has errors (it still throws "error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate"), but the answer to "Fourth question: manually computing the signature" is exactly what I needed. If you'll respond with a real answer, I would accept it.